# a marksman scores at each shot either 10, 9, 8, 7 or 6 with respective probabilities 0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

He fires 100 shots. What is the probability that: a. his aggregate score exceeds 980?  b. his aggregate score exceeds 950? 
Thanks~

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange. Since the standard deviation has to be multiplied with $\sqrt{n}$, the result $11.079$ is correct.

Comment: Thank you~ But if 11.079 is correct, these two questions do not have solutions because their probabilities are all equal to 0. I am confused haha~

Answer (score 1):

His aggregate score can be written as $X:=\sum_{i=1}^{100}X_i$ where $X_i$ denotes his score that the $i$-th shot.

Here the $X_i$ are iid.

You can find mean by applying linearity of expectation and symmetry:$$\mathbb EX=100\mathbb EX_1$$

Because there is independence you can find $\mathsf{Var}(X)$ as summation of the variances, leading to:$$\mathsf{Var}(X)=100\mathsf{Var}(X_1)$$

Then for standard deviation we find:$$\sigma_X=\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}(X)}=10\sigma_{X_1}$$

Comment: Thank you very much~ I can understand the first step. EX= 100EX1. But I am still confused by the independence of Var(X). Why can they be added up directly? Why there is independence? Can you solve the final answer for this question?a. What is the probability that his aggregate score exceeds 980? b. What is the probability that his aggregate score exceeds 950?  If I use Var(X）=100Var(X1), I can not compute the result through cumulative probability table and normal distribution. I donot why Z-score is larger than 3.0 and all the final answers are smaller than 0.001. Thank you~

Comment: What I am saying is that the "shots" are independent (so $X_1,X_2,\cdots$ are independent random variables). Missing or not missing at e.g. the first shot has no influence on missing or not missing at the second shot. If $Y$ and $Z$ are independent random variables then it can be shown that $\mathsf{Var}(Y+Z)=\mathsf{Var}Y+\mathsf{Var}Z$. My answer enables you to find mean and variance of $X$. It is okay to go for normal distribution and to be found are (approximations of) $P(X>980)$ and $P(X>950)$. Standardize $X$.

Comment: Thanks~ I now understand Var(Y+Z)= VarY+VarZ. Thank you for your clear explanation. However, when I use this standard deviation and mean, I standardize X as larger than 5 becuase mean here is 915 and standard deviation is 11.7926. When X is euqal to 980, Z is equal to (980-915)/11.07926=5.87. Then the possibility that the aggregate scores is larger than 980 is equal to 0. It is weird. Is the question wrong? Or my calculation wrong? But I  have calculated many times. So I am confused.

Comment: I think that your calculation is correct and that the answer on a) is just $0$.